# Multires Not working correctly

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to make a character And i plan on using multires to make it smooth however when i try to do so, it dissolves the character like it has been cut and turns his/her face into something butt like

Comment: In editmode try selecting everything and pressing W->RemoveDoubles. This is just a guess so it might now work. If it doesn't, could you please give some more information? Maybe a screenshot or two? Thanks!

Comment: Did not work how do i screenshot

Comment: Hit the printscr button just beside the Scroll lock button on the keyboard if you are a windows user like me. A copy of your screen is captured ... you will need to open an image editor like photoshop or gimp and paste the image with Ctrl + V or just go to the menu of the photo editor and choose paste.